# Array List initialization displayed as boolean

Tags: java

I am trying to create an object with the following constructor

```
public PageBreak(String sheetName, ArrayList<Integer> rowPageBreaks, ArrayList<Integer> columnPageBreaks)
{
    this.sheetName = sheetName;
    this.rowPageBreaks = rowPageBreaks;
    this.columnPageBreaks = columnPageBreaks;
}
```

In another method, I do the following call:

```
pageBreaks.add(new PageBreak(teamResultSheet.getName(),
                new ArrayList<Integer>().add(teamResultSheet.getRowPageBreak()), null));
```

I then get the following error message: The constructor PageBreak (String, boolean, null) is undefined.

How can I create an `ArrayList<Integer>` on the spot?

Comment: Calling the `add()` method will return a `boolean`. If you want to create just an `ArrayList` object, you just have to write `new ArrayList<Integer>()`.

Comment: @LoganKulinski:  If you have an answer next time, feel encouraged to write out an answer.  No sense in leaving knowledge like that in comments.

Comment: @Makoto Will do, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Makoto's answer is correct and explains why you are getting this error, and gives you sensible advice to create your ArrayList before you use it, you might want to know if there is any other way you can make your code more succinct.

Unlike more recent languages, such as Groovy or Kotlin, Java unfortunately does not have List literals as a language syntax. There have been some attempts to hack around this limitation; what you may have been attempting with your code is the [double brace initialization idiom](http://wiki.c2.com/?DoubleBraceInitialization):

```
pageBreaks.add(new PageBreak(teamResultSheet.getName(),
               new ArrayList<Integer>() {{add(teamResultSheet.getRowPageBreak());}},
               null);
```

Although this may look cute, it does have its drawbacks, as described in the above link.

Do you really need to pass actual `ArrayList`s to your constructor? Why not make it take `List`s, which will make it more flexible:

```
public PageBreak(String sheetName, List<Integer> rowPageBreaks, List<Integer> columnPageBreaks)
{
    ...
}
```

Then you have the freedom to pass it `ArrayList`s, as before, or any other kind of `List`:

```
pageBreaks.add(new PageBreak(teamResultSheet.getName(),
               Arrays.asList(teamResultSheet.getRowPageBreak()),
               null);
```

This looks more succinct and doesn't have the former's drawbacks; however, the list is fixed-size and immutable.

If you only want a single-element list, it's more efficient to use the following:

```
pageBreaks.add(new PageBreak(teamResultSheet.getName(),
               Collections.singletonList(teamResultSheet.getRowPageBreak()),
               null);
```

Comment: I avoided the double curly brace initializer intentionally since it makes the code less readable.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to populate your list *before* you attempt to use it.  Here's what's happening:

- You instantiate a new `ArrayList<Integer>`.
- You *immediately* call `add` on that list.
- The result of `add` is `boolean` (and consequently [***always*** returns true](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.add%28java.lang.Object%29)).
- The `boolean` result is what is interpreted, and *not* the list.